# Error when I try install a C kernel for jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-kernel

I'm trying to install the C kernel for jupyter, following the steps on the documentation. Which is

```
> pip install jupyter-c-kernel
> install_c_kernel
> jupyter-notebook
```

on the second step the following error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/install_c_kernel", line 8, in <module>
    from jupyter_client.kernelspec import KernelSpecManager
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_client.kernelspec'
```

Apparently it isn't recognizing the module and I don't know how to fix it. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`install_c_kernel --user` is the command that worked for me and is recommended on Github issues for the repo here:  https://github.com/brendan-rius/jupyter-c-kernel/issues/38

It also shows up as bash if you read the issue carefully but when you open the notebook it shows up as C.

If you already have a `.ipynb` notebook open you can choose `Kernel` from the menu and at the bottom it gives you the option to change kernels.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I haven't yet install jupyter packages for Python 3, as `install_c_kernel` runs on Python 3.

I checked it by listing the packages installed on two versions (`pip2 list` and `pip3 list`). It turned out that jupyter packages were installed for python 2, not python 3. I solved the problem by `pip3 install jupyter`.